# Should I ask my client to make their own Google Cloud account?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

I am making an RN app for a client that uses firebase. I don't want to pay or forward bills to the client. [Reading this](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/concepts), seems like you can only have one billing account for one GCP account, which means I should ask them to make their own account and invite me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should have your client create the following accounts:

1. Google Cloud Project.
2. Google Cloud Billing Account.
3. Google Payments Account.

There are many reasons why, some key points:

1. As some point you client will leave you. The amount of effort to move resources from your project to another one is not insignificant.
2. Billing responsibility. The client should be responsible for billing and payments.
3. Account ownership and control.

Provide the client with three items:

1. A Google Accounts (Gmail, Workspace, Identity) based email address for your user-based access.
2. A service account email address of a service account created in your project.
3. A document listing the permissions that you require for each account.

If you are basically doing everything for the client, consider requesting Project Editor for you user credentials. You can then assign permissions to the service account as required.

Tips:

- Enable MFA on your Google user credentials.
- Setup budgets and billing alerts. Notify yourself and your client.
- Enable Stackdriver (Operations) logging.
- Enable exporting Cloud billing data to BigQuery.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! One question. What do you mean when you say "service account"?

Comment: @nth-chile A Google Service Account is a type of credential used by programs such as the Google Cloud CLI. You create service accounts in the Google Cloud Console or the CLI. You then download the credential as a JSON file. https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts